# MySql EntityFramework execusion issue after published in Godaddy

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, model-view-controller

This is the exception which gives when I try to select all records from a Tpoic table using MySQl entity framework

> Blockquote
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Table 'cme_dev.Topic' doesn't exist\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId)\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int64& insertedId)\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()\r\n   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at MySql.Data.Entity.EFMySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.b__c(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__6()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__5()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1..GetEnumerator>b__0()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at CME_Web.Controllers.API.TopicController.getPopularTopics()

Comment: What is the message of exception?

Comment: There is no exception type showing. This is the only information I'm getting from the exception stracktrace.

Comment: Without knowing what is the exception we can only guess the problem, can not solve it. How are you getting this exception details?

Comment: When you deploy to server did you put correct libraries related to mysql into same bin folder.... mysql.data, mysql.data.entity  with correct version you used into development??

Comment: @Shiwanka Chathuranga, Yes. I have.

Comment: I have edited my question with more information

Comment: What you are sharing is stack trace. It doesn't give any information about the exception.

Comment: I have update the question with actual exception in the further analysis. It seems like a table is does not exist in the database. But the fact is that, the specified table already exist in the database.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the table `cme_dev.Topic` does not exist in the database you're connecting to.

Some steps you could try:

1. Make sure that all tables/views/functions etc have been created on
   the database.
2. Check the connection string to be sure it's pointing to the correct database

See line 3 of the stack error message `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Table 'cme_dev.Topic' doesn't exist\r\n at`

Comment: Have you checked the connection string in the code?

Comment: It's resolved, issue was on db migration. I just remigrated my database with new connection string.